# React JWT Authentication: is it secure to generate an access token together with the user data object?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, security, axios, jwt

I am implementing a JWT authentication in React and I've got this authentication context with register, login and logout:

```
    function AuthProvider({children}) {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async () => {
        try {
            const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

            if (accessToken && isValidToken(accessToken)) {
                setSession(accessToken);

                const response = await axios.get('/api/account/my-account');
                const {user} = response.data;

                dispatch({
                    type: 'INITIALIZE',
                    payload: {
                        isAuthenticated: true,
                        user,
                    },
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'INITIALIZE',
                    payload: {
                        isAuthenticated: false,
                        user: null,
                    },
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            dispatch({
                type: 'INITIALIZE',
                payload: {
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                    user: null,
                },
            });
        }
    };

    initialize();
}, []);

const login = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/account/login', {
        email,
        password,
    });
    const {accessToken, user} = response.data;

    setSession(accessToken);

    dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
            user,
        },
    });
};

const register = async (email, password, firstName, lastName) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/account/register', {
        email,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
    });
    const {accessToken, user} = response.data;

    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

    dispatch({
        type: 'REGISTER',
        payload: {
            user,
        },
    });
};

const logout = async () => {
    setSession(null);
    dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'});
};

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            ...state,
            method: 'jwt',
            login,
            logout,
            register,
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
}

export {AuthContext, AuthProvider};
```

As you can see, my API would generate an access token and would pass the user object so I can get his name and role on the next protected page.

Is this secure enough or are there better alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is secure enough as long as you enforce security in the server.

Basically, whenever a user authenticates, you provide the JWT and an unencrypted payload with user information, such as identifiers like username and email as well as access rights.  So far so good.

Now you are thinking:  If I save this stuff in say, local storage, the user could change the stored access rights and give him/herself more rights.  Well, while this could be true, it should serve for nothing because the user can only save this copy of the data, which probably controls the visibility or availability of menu items, buttons and the like according to the level of access.  What should really drive the ability to perform an action is the JWT, and the user cannot alter this JWT without access to the secret or private key used to digitally sign the token.

So yes, I'd say it is secure enough.  If you have a naughty user, know that said user cannot really post new data (for instance) if the access right is not digitally signed in the JWT.